# Can software specific or software issue questions be asked?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I've been having issues migrating to a new PC with a new version of Lightroom.

I've already done some looking up and all the help that's on the Adobe support forums have not been what my issue is.

Further to that, I want to understand the structure rather than just "you need to do this" or "that doesn't work".

I feel that this community will be the best place to ask as people will just know what I'm talking about and perhaps understand terms or phrases that may have changed since the different versions of this software.

But, my concern is that it doesn't actually ask about photography itself - just the software specifically.

Comment: Are you aware of the stackexchange site superuser.com?  

https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-lightroom

That would be the best place to ask if it's about installation or migration of software

Comment: Oh, great. Thanks. That helps me out now but I was also trying to find out about any photo editing/organising software.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this could possibly fit either here or on [Superuser](https://superuser.com). The rule of thumb I'd use is that if what you're doing is primarily a photography question, for example "how do I sepia tone a photo to make it look like <this example>", then it's probably better here. If it's primarily software/OS related, for example "Lightroom runs really slowly since I made <some change> to my machine, what can I do about it?" then it's better on Superuser. If you're not sure, just pick one, worst case scenario is that the mods will move it.